# wxPython scrolledwindow in a notebook does not scroll

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, wxnotebook

I want to have scrolled windows on tabs of a notebook. If the window is too small the contents should be scrollable. Everything is laid out correctly if the window is big enough. It also looks correctly when the window is too small to fit everything, but the scrollbars never appear, nor can I scroll with the mouse wheel. This is my minimum failing case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Title", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size(800,480), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        self.SetSizeHints(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)
        notebook = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        
        for tab in range(0,3):
            scrolled_window = wx.ScrolledWindow(notebook, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL)
            sizer = wx.GridSizer(0, 5, 0, 0)
            scrolled_window.SetScrollRate(5, 5)
            scrolled_window.SetSizer(sizer)
            notebook.AddPage(scrolled_window, "Tab %d" % tab, False)
            scrolled_window.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 1, 1)
            
            for btn in range(0,50):
                button = wx.Button(scrolled_window, wx.ID_ANY, str(btn), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
                button.SetMinSize((-1, 90))
                sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
                sizer.Fit(scrolled_window)
                self.Layout()                
    
app = wx.App(False)
main_window = MainWindow(parent=None)
main_window.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Additionally I see this assertion fail (once for every tab or whenever I change the tab):

```
(scroll_bug.py:8990): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:02:58.514: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkNotebook
```

Thanks for help

Comment: No problem running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but the issue may be trying to use a `ScrolledWindow` as a subordinate child window within the notebook.
A panel is a better fit.
Try using a `ScrolledPanel` instead e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Title", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size(800,480), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        self.SetSizeHints(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        notebook = wx.Notebook(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        
        for tab in range(0,3):
            scrolled_window = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(notebook, wx.ID_ANY)
            scrolled_window.SetupScrolling()
            notebook.AddPage(scrolled_window, "Tab %d" % tab, False)
            bsizer = wx.GridSizer(0, 5, 0, 0)            
            for btn in range(0,50):
                button = wx.Button(scrolled_window, wx.ID_ANY, str(btn), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
                button.SetMinSize((-1, 90))
                bsizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
            scrolled_window.SetSizer(bsizer)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL| wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()                
        self.Refresh()                
    
app = wx.App(False)
main_window = MainWindow(parent=None)
main_window.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]